# Rebus, funny looking word

Tags: rebus

This funny looking word is displayed in all its glory.

Can you decipher its hidden and cryptic meaning?

To question the message body is wrong.  What is the secret to meeting quality standards.

[image]

Comment: @Len Posting those these rebus puzzles is an experiment.  If people don't like them, I will stop posting them.  I am apparently much better at riddles, so maybe I should stick to what I am good at.

Comment: @Len thanks for your compliment, if the inspiration hits me after seeing some good Rebus puzzles, I will try again, but only if I am confident it will be a challenge to others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Flip-flops. This is what you get when you flip "flops".